# dBase .DBF null boolean value

Tags: c#, .net, odbc, connection-string, dbf

I've strange problem: my dbf file have row with null boolean field. When I try to read this row from dbf file ODBC returns `true` for this field, but I want get `null` or `false`.

I test this in two operation systems:

- In Windows 7 64 bit null boolean in select returns me `false`
- In Windows 2008 Server null boolean in select returns me `true`

Where is the problem? How I can setup my connection string to extort return in all systems `false` or `null` when boolean field has `null` value?

I'm using .NET with standard ODBC connector. 
My connection string is: `"Driver={Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)};Data Source=C:\dest_dir"`

Comment: You can try using the bool? type (nullable type).
Maybe your database have a constraint which returns true if null.

Comment: Unfortunately i can't change data type in dbf file. I'm sure this is not database settings problem because im testing the same file in different operating system and i have different result.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by asking.  Is is really a dBASE file or Visual FoxPro based (.dbf) file.  If Foxpro, I would start with the VFP OleDB provider instead located [here...](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=14839)